# Finding the frequency of opamp to get a specific voltage gain

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, non-inverting, gain-bandwidth-product

In the following question, they ask for the frequency at which the gain would be 1.41 V/V. The dc or low frequency closed loop gain is 2V/V (6 dB). Is the solution of the following question done correctly? I think it is wrong as they get the answer for frequency to be 5MHz, while 5Mhz is the closed loop 3db frequency of the amplifier. The frequency resulting in 1.41 V/V gain aught to be larger than that. Please tell me if their solution is correct or not and if it is not then what is the correct one?
[image]

Comment: The answer looks good for me (6dB - 3dB = 3dB = 1.41 V/V)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/200665/bandwidth-of-inverting-and-non-inverting-op-amps. Answer looks correct.

Comment: The question is asking for frequency. What r u talking about?